# throw new error_1.MongoInvalidArgumentError('Update document requires atomic operators');

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm getting `(throw new error_1.MongoInvalidArgumentError('Update document requires atomic operators'); )`
this type of error
Here is the full code for put endpoint:

```
app.put('/todo/:id', async (req, res) => 
  { 
    const id = req.params.id; const data = req.body; 
    console.log(data); 
    const filter = { _id: ObjectId(id) }; 
    const options = { upsert: true }; 
    const updateDoc = { $set: { name: data.name, message: data.message, }, }; 
    const result = await dataCollections.updateOne(filter, options, updateDoc); 
    res.send(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the parameters in the wrong order, update document comes before options, try this:

```
const result = await dataCollections.updateOne(filter,  updateDoc, options);
```